How to change the value of parameter of a class when the bound object's value has changed in Flutter/Dart?
I'm new to programming and don't know what I am doing, but trying to understand.
late CabsOfAcacia Sinan = CabsOfAcacia('Sinan', 'assets/taxi.png', cabsLocations.elementAt(0), cabsDistanceFromUser.elementAt(0));

  late CabsOfAcacia Seyit = CabsOfAcacia('Seyit', 'assets/taxi.png', cabsLocations.elementAt(1), cabsDistanceFromUser.elementAt(1));

  late CabsOfAcacia OsmanAga = CabsOfAcacia('Osman Aga', 'assets/taxi.png', cabsLocations.elementAt(2), cabsDistanceFromUser.elementAt(2));

  late CabsOfAcacia AliKemal = CabsOfAcacia('Ali Kemal', 'assets/taxi.png', cabsLocations.elementAt(3), cabsDistanceFromUser.elementAt(3));

  late CabsOfAcacia ArifKeser = CabsOfAcacia('Arif Keser', 'assets/taxi.png', cabsLocations.elementAt(4), cabsDistanceFromUser.elementAt(4));


  late List<double?>cabsDistanceFromUser = [null,null,null,null,null];

///this is the class
class CabsOfAcacia{
  late final String nameOfCab;
  late final String assetPathOfCab;
  late final LatLng locationOfCab;
  late final double? distanceFromUserOfCab;

  CabsOfAcacia(
    this.nameOfCab, 
    this.assetPathOfCab, 
    this.locationOfCab, 
    this.distanceFromUserOfCab);
}

What I am trying to do is; CabsOfAcacia is a class that I created, and they have a parameter called distanceFromUserOfCab. That double value is coming from the List named cabsDistanceFromUser's i'th element. And after some steps in my app, the values in that list are updated.
But the value of the CabsOfAcacia object's cabsDistanceFromUser is stuck to its first value which is null. I can succesfully update the list -where the value of cabsDistanceFromUser is coming from- but the value is still the value in the beginning, again, which is null.
I don't know if I did express the problem clearly, that's my first time ever asking something on web. I feel like a caveman.
Thank you.

Since your properties are late final, you cannot expect their value to change later on. If you define it this way:
class CabsOfAcacia{
  final String nameOfCab;
  final String assetPathOfCab;
  final LatLng locationOfCab;
  double distanceFromUserOfCab;

  CabsOfAcacia(
    this.nameOfCab, 
    this.assetPathOfCab, 
    this.locationOfCab,
    {
       this.distanceFromUserOfCab = 0,
    }
  );
}

You can call the instance of this object (for example, the Sinan var in your example), and change the value of its distanceFromUserOfCab with:
Sinan.distanceFromUserOfCab = cabsDistanceFromUser.elementAt(0);

But there is no binding involved there, so changing the values in the cabsDistanceFromUser list will not automagically update the values in the various CabsOfAcacia instances.
